# What is the risk of not catching exceptions in a CGI script

Tags: python, exception, cgi

I have a python CGI script that takes several query strings as arguments. 
The query strings are generated by another script, so there is little possibility to get illegal arguments,
unless some "naughty" user changes them intentionally.
A illegal argument may throw a exception (e.g.  int() function get non-numerical inputs),
but does it make sense to write some codes to catch such rare errors? Any security risk or performance penalty if not caught?

I know the page may go ugly if exceptions are not nicely handled, but a naughty user deserves it, right?

Answer (score 1):

Any unhandled exception causes program to terminate.

That means if your program is doing some thing and exception occurs it will shutdown in an unclean fashion without releasing resources.

Any ways CGI is obsolete use Django, Flask, Web2py or something.